# Entire Function is Constant with $Re(f(z))^2 = Im(f(z)) \forall z \in C$

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $f$ is an entire function with $Re(f(z))^2 = Im(f(z)) \forall z \in C$. Show that $f$ is constant.

So far, I have that since $f$ is entire, we can use cauchy riemann equations and hence $u_x = v_y , u_y = -v_x$.

Let $f = u+iv$ where $U,V$ real valued functions so Now we have that $Re(f(z))^2 = u^2 =v = Im(f(z)$. We get :

$v_x = 2u\cdot u_x= -u_y$ and $v_y = 2u\cdot u_y = u_x$ by the C-R equations.

Now I am unsure as to where to go next. My idea is equating $2u = u_x/u_y = -u_y/u_x$ and proving that this implies $u$ is a constant. Is this correct? Is there a better approach to this? How can I go about proving the final equality easily?

Comment: You can't divide by $u_y,u_x$, after all you are trying to prove that they are $0$ !

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3807009/let-f-be-an-analytic-function-such-that-operatornameimfz-operatorname/3807040#3807040

Comment: My mistake on this oversight..

Comment: Yes, This is a good proof. Although I think the one below will also suffice despite it being slightly weak.

Comment: There's actually a stronger result which is quite easy to prove: if there's a $\mathcal{C}^1$ function $G$ (with $0$ a regular value), then $G(f)=0$ impliesthat $f$ is constant. For a proof see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3834561/a-complex-function-is-constant-if-it-satisfies-one-of-these-properties/3834584#3834584

Answer (score 0):

\begin{eqnarray}
&&2u\cdot u_x= -u_y\ \text{and}\ 2u\cdot u_y= u_x\\
&\Rightarrow& 2u(u_y^2+u_x^2)=0\\
&\Rightarrow& u_y=u_x=0\ \text{or}\ u=0\\
&\Rightarrow& v_x=v_y=0
\end{eqnarray}

This implies $v$ is constant. But we have $u^2=v$, and hence $u^2$ is constant, which implies $u$ is constant as we have assumed $u$ is continuous.

Comment: Your argumentation is flawed, because $u_x=u_y=0$, so how can we divide by them?

Comment: Sorry, my bad, corrected it.

Comment: Much better. I think the argument is still formulated somewhat on the short side, as $$(u_x(z) = 0 \text{ and } u_y(z)=0) \text{ or } u(z)=0 \text{ for all } z\in\mathbb C \implies u \text{ constant}$$ still needs to be proven (my answer has the same gap, admittedly).

Comment: First of all the gap is quite easy to prove considering the fact, that for a real-valued continuous function $f$, if $f.f'=0$, then $f^2=c$ for some constant (by integration). Also we dont need to prove that, as I have done in my edited solution

Answer (score 0):

We can argument as follows:
\begin{split}\renewcommand{\Re}{\operatorname{Re}}\frac{\partial\Re (f(z))}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial [\Re(f(z))^2]}{\partial y}&=2\Re(f(z))\frac{\partial\Re(f(z))}{\partial y}\\&=-2\Re(f(z))\frac{\partial[\Re(f(z))^2]}{\partial x}=-4\Re(f(z))^2\frac{\partial\Re(f(z))}{\partial x},\end{split}

so for every $z$ we have either $\frac{\partial\Re(f(z))}{\partial x}=0$ or $\Re(f(z))^2=-\frac14$.